# Creating data continuously using rnorm until an outlier occurs in R

Tags: r, while-loop, repeat

Sorry for the confusing title, but i wasn't sure how to title what i am trying to do. My objective is to create a dataset of 1000 obs each would be the length of the run. I have created a phase1 dataset, from which a set of control limits are produced. What i am trying to do now is create a phase2 dataset most likely using rnorm. what im trying to do is create a repeat loop that will continuously create values in the phase2 dataset until one of those values is outside of the control limits produced from the phase1 dataset.  for example if i had 3.0 and -3.0 as control limits the phase2 dataset would create a bunch of  observations until obs 398 when the value here happens to be 3.45, thus stopping the creation of data. my objective is then to record the number 398. Furthermore,  I am then trying to loop the code back to the phase1 dataset/ control limits portion and create a new set of control limits and then run another phase2, until i have 1000 run lengths recorded. the code i have for the phase1/ control limits works fine and looks like this:

```
nphase1=50
nphase2=1000
varcount=1
meanshift= 0
sigmashift= 1


##### phase1 dataset/ control limits #####

phase1 <- matrix(rnorm(nphase1*varcount, 0, 1), nrow = nphase1, ncol=varcount)
mean_var <- apply(phase1, 2, mean)
std_var <- apply(phase1, 2, sd)
df_var <- data.frame(mean_var, std_var)

Upper_SPC_Limit_Method1 <- with(df_var, mean_var + 3 * std_var)
Lower_SPC_Limit_Method1 <- with(df_var, mean_var - 3 * std_var)
df_control_limits<- data.frame(Upper_SPC_Limit_Method1, Lower_SPC_Limit_Method1)
```

I have previously created this code in SAS and it looks like this. might be a better reference for what i am trying to achieve then me trying to explain it.

```
%macro phase2_dataset (n=,varcount=, meanshift=, sigmashift=, nphase1=,simID=,);
%do z=1 %to &n;
 %phase1_dataset (n=&nphase1, varcount=&varcount);
    data phase2; set control_limits n=lastobs;
       call streaminit(0);
       do until (phase2_var1<Lower_SPC_limit_method1_var1 or
                 phase2_var1>Upper_SPC_limit_method1_var1);
        phase2_var1 = rand("normal", &meanshift, &sigmashift); 
        output;
        end;

    run;
 ods exclude all; 
 proc means data=phase2;
 var phase2_var1;
 ods output summary=x;
 run; 
 ods select all; 
 data run_length; set x;
 keep Phase2_var1_n;
 run; 
proc append base= QA.Phase2_dataset&simID data=Run_length force; run;    
%end;
%mend;
```

Also been doing research about using a while loop in replace of the repeat loop. 
 Im new to R so Any ideas you are able to throw my way are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a while loop indeed seems to be the way to go. Here's what I think you're looking for:

```
set.seed(10) #Making results reproducible

replicate(100, { #100 is easier to display here
  phase1 <- matrix(rnorm(nphase1*varcount, 0, 1), nrow = nphase1, ncol=varcount)
  mean_var <- colMeans(phase1) #Slightly better than apply
  std_var <- apply(phase1, 2, sd)
  df_var <- data.frame(mean_var, std_var)

  Upper_SPC_Limit_Method1 <- with(df_var, mean_var + 3 * std_var)
  Lower_SPC_Limit_Method1 <- with(df_var, mean_var - 3 * std_var)
  df_control_limits<- data.frame(Upper_SPC_Limit_Method1, Lower_SPC_Limit_Method1)

  #Phase 2

  x <- 0
  count <- 0

  while(x > Lower_SPC_Limit_Method1 && x < Upper_SPC_Limit_Method1) {
    x <- rnorm(1)
    count <- count + 1
  }
  count
})
```

The result is:

```
  [1]  225   91   97  118  304  275  550   58  115    6  218   63  176  100  308  844   90 2758
 [19]  161  311 1462  717 2446   74  175   91  331  210  118 1517  420   32   39  201  350   89
 [37]   64  385  212    4   72  730  151    7 1159   65   36  333   97  306  531 1502   26   18
 [55]   67  329   75  532   64  427   39  352  283  483   19    9    2 1018  137  160  223   98
 [73]   15  182   98   41   25 1136  405  474 1025 1331  159   70   84  129  233    2   41   66
 [91]    1   23    8  325   10  455  363  351  108    3
```

If performance becomes a problem, perhaps it would be interesting to explore some improvements, like creating more numbers with `rnorm()` at a time and then counting how many are necessary to exceed the limits and repeat if necessary.

Comment: That is what i was trying to do pretty much, thanks. Quick follow-up, to save a dataframe of those results I can just add something like DF_ARL<- data.frame( before the replicate( 100,...... correct?

Comment: Yes, though I don't see why yo would save that as a one-column data.frame. You can of course create a dataframe from it afterwards if you have another column to add anyway.

Comment: I may not be understanding completely, but the `while` loop seems horribly inefficient. Could take thousands of draws to find something outside the limits. Rather, you should draw a variable uniform on `[0,F^-1(Lower_limit)]U[F^-1(Upper_limit),1]`, where `F` is the standard normal CDF (e.g., multiply a U(0,1) draw by `F^-1(Lower)+1-F^-1(Upper)`).

Comment: @MichaelChirico I agree the `while` can be very inefficient, specially if the limits are changed to greater ranges (though at some point it would be impossible without also adjusting `rnorm`'s mean and sd). Maybe you can post your soluton? I'd love to see the smart math-way of doing this.

Comment: I eliminated the while loop, but I don't think it's worthy of a separate answer. I wasn't sure why you were returning `count` but it seemed obsolete once the loop was cut. Anyway if you or @AdamEhrenborg don't follow what I did, I can annotate it.

Comment: @MichaelChirico `count` is the number of tries (which depend on the random result of `rnorm` necessary to generate a value outside the limits, and it's returned because for each of the 100 replications there's a different number of tries. Your suggestion doesn't return the same thing. Maybe you missed something?

Comment: @MichaelChirico and by the way, it's worth an answer if it's a real improvement over another answer, which would be the case here, since I only wrote the while loop. But if you're not going to add one, it's better to add the alternative below instead of replacing the current code, specially after it's been accepted and discussed in the comments.

Comment: It appears I totally misunderstood the question. Indeed a `while` loop may be best. The only improvement I can suggest is do draw `ceiling(1/p)` draws at a time, where `p` is the probability of an acceptable draw (since `1/p` is the number of draws expected before a success).

Comment: @MichaelChirico You *really* should not edit code in someone else's answer.  If you feel something needs to be addressed you may do so in the comments, but your edit should not have been approved.